# How to extract fields from a request payload and add it to hashmap on a POST request which will be invoked by n times?

Tags: java, json, rest

Im using JAX-RX for the server. When client does a POST call to my server , I need to get two fields from the POST body payload.Im using POJO for extracting the fields and I need to add it the Hashmap. This hashmap should be having 4 entries.I tried

```
@Path("/entity/")

public class StudentModel {

public Map<String, Integer> studentMap = new HashMap<>();

HashSet<String> studentCreated = new HashSet<>(); 
/*This set is basically to add the names of students added which will be used by PATCH method*/ 

@Path("{id}/student")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createRecord(Student student) {
       
        studentCreated.add(student.getName());
        studentMap.put(student.getName(),student.getPort());
        System.out.println("studentName is "+student.getName()+" ID is "+student.getID());
        return Response.ok().status(201).entity("{}").build();
    }
@Path("{id}/student/")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getStudentandID(){
       return Response.ok().entity(studentMap).build();

    }
```

Here Student is the POJO class which has getters and setters for the POST body payload.4 POST calls will be made  from the client and I need HashMap of StudentName and ID like
{Student1=1,Student2=2,Student3=3,Student4=4} .In the GET Method I need to return the complete Hashmap. Basically each POST call should add entries to the HashMap and the end , GET should return the complete HashMap.

Issue is when I do a GET on {id}/student/ I'm getting only 1 record (mostly the last POST call record )
{student4=4}.
Please help how do I get all 4 records in HashMap.

I tried above piece of code But Im getting only 1 record instead of 4 record

Comment: You should call a student method without a parameter to get all records.

Comment: @Roman, method seems to not to filter per id, so should return entire map

Comment: @data01 where map are stored ?

Comment: Please paste the complete codes and let's check how studentMap is maintained. Generally as stateless of HTTP, you need to store the POST result in another central persistence store such as database or redis.

Comment: Pasted complete code , Please check

Comment: Making the map static worked , Thanks